# Should one tell their private plans?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rashi

Where is the Rashi that states if you want something to happen dont tell others your plans - like learning a certain amount if Perakim etcs. Thanks.

Comment: Weclome to Mi Yodeya. Please clarify your question further. I don't understand "like learning a certain amount if Perek etcs".

Comment: ... like learning a certain amount of** Perekim.

Comment: Rashi basically states "if you want something to happen dont reveal it to others," and gives examples. Ive seen it before i jist cant find it again

Comment: See also http://web.archive.org/web/20080509162804/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_vayera.html

Answer (score 3):

Sanhedrin 26b s.v.מפר מחשבות ערומים See his second pshat [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=26b&format=pdf).

> ל״א מחשבה שאדם
>    מחשב כך וכך אעשה כך וכך תעלה
>    בידי מועלת להשבית הדבר שאין
>    מחשבתו מתקיימת אפילו לדבר תורה
>    כגון האומר עד יום פלוני אסיים כך
>    וכך מסכתות בגירסא:

Comment: shkoyech very good Metsia.  perhaps you can explain that the Gemara explains this through a pasuk

Comment: @kouty would that make it a better answer? All he wanted was to source this Rashi. As it is I thought quoting the words in Rashi was lifnim mishuras hadin.